# i got url problems while using laravel

Tags: javascript, php

My route is defined as under and i create `php artisan make:conroller --resource`
when i run `php artisan` its give me route list like

```
Posts posts   posts.store App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@store
Get   posts/create  posts.create App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@create
```

but as i enter url in http://localhost/laravelblog/posts/create its give me error

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 179)

can some one help what is problem ?

```
Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use php build-in server, add the protocol in url:

```
http://localhost:8000/laravelblog/posts/create
```

If you use an XAMPP application, reffer to the `public/` directory:

```
http://localhost/laravelblog/public/posts/create
```

Comment: Thanks i solved it by giving absolute path because just posts path is not working for me